# struggling to work out character encoding

Tags: linux, unicode, encoding, utf-8

Hello i am hoping someone can help me or point me in the right direction with opening a file in a readable format. I have tried opening with windows standard text editor, notepad ++, Ubant text editor and various other programs and every time certain characters are unreadable. i have attached  a small snipet in the hope someone recognises what the charater encoding is or can help me with a better application to view it. Thanks in advance

```
4oó.ª<  ˜?²ìxÓR           
Œñ%°ãYºu©Ù´ø¥T 
@@  zD  @@  ðA „×     áõ      ðA                                              ÈB                                                     '      €?            zC  HB   A   A  ÈB                            ÍÌÌ<    3 MüZfKG­ñÙZ·Vè     €?    @B       @@  zD  @@  ðA „×     áõ      ðA                                              ÈB                                                     '      €?            zC  HB   A   A  ÈB                            ÍÌÌ<     MüZfKG­ñÙZ·Vè     €?    @B       @@  zD  @@  ðA „×     áõ      ðA                                              ÈB                                                     '      €?            zC  HB   A   A  ÈB                                    Œñ%°ãYºu©Ù´ø¥T     ÈC©{,BC²¹ÒÅ“ì&‹bõ    ©{,BC²¹ÒÅ“ì&‹bõ    ÜCnÁ„
.ìÔ¾Žž›‚”p                                                                                                                    4oó.ª<    ˜?²ìxÓR    FÃ#    Œñ%°ãYºu©Ù´ø¥T      A Œñ%°ãYºu©Ù´ø¥T     ´ 4oó.ª< ˜?²ìxÓR            Œñ%°ãYºu©Ù´ø¥T     ÈB Œñ%°ãYºu©Ù´ø¥T       H 4oó.ª<  ˜?²ìxÓR            4oó.ª<   ˜?²ìxÓR            ñ
Œð/˜™Df¨°æNû‚Ð
```

Comment: First: are you **sure** that this is a text file? At first glance it looks like it's simply a binary file that's not meant to (directly) represent text at all.

Comment: By copying this to StackOverflow as text, your software has already decoded the file using some encoding... so this information is not useful. What does `file name_of_the_file` say?

Comment: Looking at this some more I'm pretty sure that is some structured binary file that's not meant to be text at all. See for example the fact that despite an overall visible structure (which would usually be very visible if a text was displayed using the wrong encoding) the substring `˜?²ìxÓR` occurs multiple times. Assuming this is decoded using ISO-8859-1 (and the `?` isn't just a replacement for one of the unassigned spots), then that would be the bytes `7E 3F B2 EC 78 D3 52`. Also `Œñ%°ãYºu©Ù´ø¥T` occurs 6 times.

Comment: Actually the presence of `Œ` suggests this wasn't decoded using ISO-8859-1 at all, but probably ISO-8859-15. Anyway: it would be immensely more useful if you could provide a hexdump of this (or just do what @Thomas) suggested and use the `file` application, it's usually pretty good at detecting the file type.

Comment: @JoachimSauer It doesn't re-encode as ISO-8859-15 either due to the presence of `˜`. It looks like `~` but it's actually U+02DC SMALL TILDE.

Comment: Yeah, just realized that -15 also makes no sense. `´` is in -1 but not in -15. Whatever it is: OP should look at a hexdump (and/or [edit] the question to include one).